# Generate unique serial from id number

Tags: mysql

I have a database that increases id incrementally. I need a function that converts that id to a unique number between 0 and 1000. (the actual max is much larger but just for simplicity's sake.)

```
1 => 3301, 
2 => 0234, 
3 => 7928,
4 => 9821
```

The number generated cannot have duplicates.
It can not be incremental.
Need it generated on the fly (not create a table of uniform numbers to read from)

I thought a hash function but there is a possibility for collisions.
Random numbers could also have duplicates.
I need a minimal perfect hash function but cannot find a simple solution.

Comment: If you transform numbers between 0 and 1000 to another set of numbers between 0 and 1000, you will just arbitrarily be mapping one number to another. What is wrong with incremental IDs?

Comment: that's exactly what I need to do... transform from one set to another, but I don't know a simple function to accomplish this. The reason id's need to be transformed because my boss wants to create a website to search database by this unique id. He thinks if people know it's incremental, they could do the search incrementally to find every item in database.

Comment: How important is it that people not be able to find all items? If a hash function of some kind is used, someone could discover the hash function and then search incrementally anyways. To make this actually cryptographically secure, you either need to generate something random and store it or encrypt the ids with a secret key that others cannot get.

Comment: I agree, but this is how he wants it. each id will take the form 01-******, at first i just turned the number into a hex such as 01-0002af, but he figures it's too easy to count from that. it doesn't have to be super secure, I guess he figures the average person won't try to crack a hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the criteria are sort of vague (good enough to fool the average person), I am unsure exactly which route to take. Here are some ideas:

1. You could use a [Pearson hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_hashing). According to the Wikipedia page:

   > Given a small, privileged set of inputs (e.g., reserved words for a compiler), the permutation table can be adjusted so that those inputs yield distinct hash values, producing what is called a perfect hash function.
2. You could just use a complicated looking one-to-one mathematical function. The drawback of this is that it would be difficult to make one that was not strictly increasing or strictly decreasing due to the one-to-one requirement. If you did something like `(id ^ 2) + id * 2`, the interval between ids would change and it wouldn't be immediately obvious what the function was without knowing the original ids.
3. You could do something like this:

   ```
   new_id = (old_id << 4) + arbitrary_4bit_hash(old_id);
   ```

   This would give the unique IDs and it wouldn't be immediately obvious that the first 4 bits are just garbage (especially when reading the numbers in decimal format). Like the last option, the new IDs would be in the same order as the old ones. I don't know if that would be a problem.
4. You could just hardcode all ID conversions by making a lookup array full of "random" numbers.
5. You could use some kind of hash function generator like [gperf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/).

   > GNU gperf is a perfect hash function generator. For a given list of strings, it produces a hash function and hash table, in form of C or C++ code, for looking up a value depending on the input string. The hash function is perfect, which means that the hash table has no collisions, and the hash table lookup needs a single string comparison only.
6. You could encrypt the ids with a key using a cryptographically secure mechanism.

Hopefully one of these works for you.

**Update**

Here is the rotational shift the OP requested:

```
function map($number)
{
    // Shift the high bits down to the low end and the low bits
    // down to the high end
    // Also, mask out all but 10 bits. This allows unique mappings
    // from 0-1023 to 0-1023
    $high_bits = 0b0000001111111000 & $number;
    $new_low_bits = $high_bits >> 3;
    $low_bits =  0b0000000000000111 & $number;
    $new_high_bits = $low_bits << 7;
    // Recombine bits
    $new_number = $new_high_bits | $new_low_bits;
    return $new_number;
}

function demap($number)
{
    // Shift the high bits down to the low end and the low bits
    // down to the high end
    $high_bits = 0b0000001110000000 & $number;
    $new_low_bits = $high_bits >> 7;
    $low_bits =  0b0000000001111111 & $number;
    $new_high_bits = $low_bits << 3;
    // Recombine bits
    $new_number = $new_high_bits | $new_low_bits;
    return $new_number;
}
```

This method has its advantages and disadvantages. The main disadvantage that I can think of (besides the security aspect) is that for lower IDs consecutive numbers will be exactly the same (multiplicative) interval apart until digits start wrapping around. That is to say

```
map(1) * 2 == map(2)
map(1) * 3 == map(3)
```

This happens, of course, because with lower numbers, all the higher bits are 0, so the map function is equivalent to just shifting. This is why I suggested using pseudo-random data for the lower bits rather than the higher bits of the number. It would make the regular interval less noticeable. To help mitigate this problem, the function I wrote shifts only the first 3 bits and rotates the rest. By doing this, the regular interval will be less noticeable for all IDs greater than 7.

Comment: I really like option 2 and 3. The others create way too many characters. The problem I still have is the range. if I have 1000 id's I need each one mapped to a unique serial in the range of [0, 1000]. Both options 2 and 3 create larger numbers. I could just make a table and jumble 0 to 1000 but i'd prefer to generate them as I go. it's seems like there should be an easy function that will do this. maybe push all bits left and put the farthest bit to the left rotated to the beggining. such as 100101 to 001011. but how do i accomplish this?

Comment: @JohnBaker It depends. What language are do you want to do it in?

Comment: @JohnBaker I edited my answer. Because the function uses binary operations, the range is 0-1024 rather than 0-1000. Is that ok?

Comment: Sorry, actually 0-1023

Comment: Yes that helps a lot, I think this is probably the option i'll go with. I would push your comment up but i'm new to stack overflow so i'm not allowed to you. Thank you everyone

Comment: @JohnBaker I'm glad I could help! You can mark the answer as accepted if this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it doesn't have to be numerical? What about an MD5-Hash?

select md5(id+rand(10000)) from ...

Comment: But what about possible collisions. He mentioned this.

Comment: ok - so leave the rand() - i don't really know about ist, but shouldn't the MD5 up to a VERY high number unique?

Comment: Probably. Without explicitly checking them all I wouldn't rely on it though.